# making multiple firefox desktop icons for ubuntu 20.04

Tags: firefox

MY SPECS
i am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64 on a Lenovo ThinkPad E590 15.6 laptop.

MY PROBLEM
hello, i am new to Ubuntu and downloaded and installed it 3 days ago, my previous operating system was Linux Mint 19.3, and on Linux mint i had a lot of mozzila firefox accounts on my desktop, and i would make a new desktop icon for each of my firefox accounts

in this video i show how i made my firefox icons

https://www.bitchute.com/video/babRboVoDinK/

i would like to ask if there is a way for me to make new firefox profile icons onto my desktop, and if so, how, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just tested on Ubuntu 20.04, and the exact steps outlined in the video you linked work. If you don't have an application for editing desktop files, simply use any text editor, or a terminal window. You can just run `cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/Desktop/profile1.desktop` and then open it with either

> gedit  ~/Desktop/profile1.desktop

or

> nano ~/Desktop/profile1.desktop

Find the line that starts with `Exec=` and change it to be `Exec=firefox -P "profileName"`.

From the man pages on [firefox](https://linux.die.net/man/1/firefox):

> -P profile
>
> > Start with profile.

You can also change the `name` value if you would like it to show a different name in a file manager with some desktop systems.

### EDIT

If it opens in a text editor when you double click it, make sure the file is executable, and right click the file and choose "Allow launching"

Comment: Sorry, just realized I put the wrong paths in the nano and gedit commands. Fixed!